# JUnit 5 not working with IntelliJ IDEA anymore

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

I had this working 3 day's ago and then since I pulled some code down from me and my buddies git repo, Junit 5 won't work anymore.  Like I said, I was able to run Junit unit tests before I pulled from the repo now I can't.  Here are print screens with more info.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have checked the path listed for Junit dependancies and the jar files do exist there.  I definitely have Junit on my computer as I had unit tests working before and I did not delete any files since.  Any help would be wonderful as I have been wrestling and searching this for some time now.

Answer (score 1):

You should try updating to the latest Intellij 2017.3, as they state that they improved their Junit 5 support.

Comment: I deleted my repo and cloned the original remote repo and again and it seems to fix the issue